# Calculate max value and set background to equal parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying now to:

1. Get number from text **DONE**
2. Set it to equal for `this` value **DONE**
3. Get a value a get max **DONE**

**4. and set the max value `parent` background to for example `background: #000;`**

So my question is how i gonna get a parent of the **MAX** value what was calculated before?

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGMxKK)

```js
$('.views').each(function(){
    valText = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr('value', valText);
});

var numbers = $(".views").map(function(){
    return parseFloat(this.getAttribute('value')) || -Infinity;
});

var calculate = Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);
$("#max").html(calculate);
```

```html
<div><div class="views" >10</div></div>
<div><div class="views" >1</div></div>
<div><div class="views" >7</div></div>
<div><div class="views" >5</div></div>
<div><div class="views" >3</div></div>
```

Max value is:

```
<p>Max value is: <span id="max"></span></p>
```

Comment: And what would be the parent of the `views` elements, they all seem to be siblings anyway and have the same parent ?

Comment: And, `<div>` elements don't have values.

Comment: @adeneo: sorry i paste old HTML.. and there is script for that `$('.views').each(function(){
    valText = $(this).text();
    $(this).attr('value', valText);
});`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being a little tricky, reducing the collection to the one with the highest number inside

```
var el = $('.views').toArray().reduce(function(a,b) {
    return (+$(a).text()) > (+$(b).text()) ? $(a) : $(b);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/g1up11zs/)

To get the parent, simply

```
el.parent();
```

Comment: That's, smart.. Thanks a lot man.. appreciate that for your help

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoyzMd

```
var el = $('.views').toArray().reduce(function(a,b) {
    return (+$(a).text()) > (+$(b).text()) ? $(a) : $(b);
});

$("#max").html(el);
$("#max").parent().css({'background-color':'red'})
```

Like that?

Comment: No I used your provided codepen and made a fork. you must have updated your codepen with his answer, I just added what I thought it was missing. Wasn't trying to steal thunder.